# Installing HTTPModule into GAC

Tags: sharepoint, gac, httpmodule

While playing around with Sharepoint and WCF, I came across an article - [Sharepoint 2007 and WCF](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-5-SharePoint_2007_as_a_WCF_host_-_Step_-4,_Write_a_Virtual_Path_Provider.aspx)
in which the author stated the need to fix the Virtual Path Provider. He accomplished this with an HTTPModule. However, since this is a global fix, I am wondering what is the best way to install the new module into GAC? Is this the same process as installing an assembly into GAC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register HTTPModule with any specific web application. So when you need to deploy wcf service to sharepoint 2007, you will need to deploy the http module dll to gac and then register the http module in the web.config of the sharepoint web application( there will be a httpmodule section in the web.config)

This essentially means that the httpmodule is now registered only with the particular webapplication and not globally(though the dll is deployed globally)

Hope this helps.